# Extending immutable.is for arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm looking for an easy way to deeply compare objects & arrays that can contain Immutable.js objects. To make it easier to write tests.

Look at the following snipped. (Modified from the example code on the immutable.js website)

```js
const { Map, is, List } = require('immutable@4.0.0-rc.10')
const map1 = Map({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 })
const map2 = Map({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 })
assert.equal(map1 !== map2, true)
assert.equal(Object.is(map1, map2), false)
assert.equal(is(map1, map2), true)
assert.equal(is(List([map1, map2]), List([map1, map2])), true)
assert.equal(is(Map({map1, map2}), Map({map1, map2})), true)
/* I'd like these last two to be true */
assert.equal(is([map1, map2], [map1, map2]), true) // fails
assert.equal(is({map1, map2}, {map1, map2}), true) // fails
```

Is there any existing library or function that will do that? Or is there an easy way to spot immutable Records, Lists, and Maps if I'm writing my own comparator?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, have you considered using ChaiJS's `deep.equal()`? https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep

Comment: The normal deep.equal() doesn't work for Immutable objects. There's also `chai-immutable` that will override equal for Immutable objects, but doesn't work when they are nested under normal arrays or objects. So neither will work.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to check a values "access modifier" ... const  or let

Comment: In the last 2 I'd expect `[map1, map2]` to deeply equal `[map1, map2]` and `{map1, map2}` to deeply equal `{map1, map2}` so shouldn't the test be `assert.equal(is([map1, map2], [map1, map2]), true)` instead of false, or am I missing something?

Comment: I was trying to make it clear that they're returning `false` right now and that's the problem. I'll change it if that'll be more clear.

Comment: Got it. Well, I have a working example using chai. If you're open to using it I'll post an answer.

Comment: I'm open to using chai, but I'll need to compare more than one level deep. Even thought that's not in the example. I was just trying to get the idea across.

Comment: @wmil I quickly tried a little nesting by changing up the Maps: `const mapA = Map({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1});
  const mapB = Map({a: mapA, b: 1, c: 1});
  const map1 = Map({a: mapB, b: 1, c: 1});
  const map2 = Map({a: mapB, b: 1, c: 1});` and it still seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following tests using [Chai's `.deep` property](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep) exhibits the behavior you're looking for:

```
const {expect} = require('chai');
const {Map, List} = require('immutable');

describe('this stuff', () => {
  const map1 = Map({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1});
  const map2 = Map({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1});
  it('should behave itself', () => {
    expect(map1).not.to.equal(map2);
    expect(Object.is(map1, map2)).to.be.false;
    expect(map1).to.deep.equal(map2);
    expect(List([map1, map2])).to.deep.equal(List([map1, map2]));
    expect(Map({map1, map2})).to.deep.equal(Map({map1, map2}));
    expect([map1, map2]).to.deep.equal([map1, map2]);
    expect({map1, map2}).to.deep.equal({map1, map2});
  });
});
```

Alternatively, without pulling in Chai (especially useful if the use case is *not* in a test suite):

```
assert([map1, map2].every((map, i) => is(map, [map1, map2][i])));
assert(Object.values({map1, map2}).every((map, i) => is(map, Object.values({map1, map2})[i])));
```

Comment: That first version only incidentally works, the internal structure of immutable.js objects isn't guaranteed. It'll fail with `const map2 = Map({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 1 }).set('b', 1);`